# Map Literals to Object Properties/Values

Tags: c#

For eg, my input XML is look like this.

```
<root>
<myelemt>
<input type="variable">
<variable>STARTDATE</variable>
<variable>CUSTOMERNAME</variable>
</input>
</myelemt>
</root>
```

it is deserialized and loaded into the object MyXmlElemtObj

in my code i have written like this,

```
 if(MyXmlElemtObj.input.variable.ToUpper() == "STARTDATE")
    ProcessObjectB(ObjectA.OrderDate);

if(MyXmlElemtObj.input.variable.ToUpper() == "CUSTOMERNAME")
    ProcessObjectB(ObjectC.UserName);
```

Here I am mapping those input literals to some objects value.

The one thing that scares me is seeing some ** hard-coded literals** all over my code.

Instead i would like to write something like `ProcessObjectB(Common.GetMappedvalue(MyXmlElemtObj.input.variable));`

Is there a way to isolate this mapping thing to common class, where i will predefine
which literal is mapped to which values. The problem is the values are of objects created at the run time.

**If my question is making sense then So how do i achieve this?**

I think i have given all the necessary details. if anything is missing please metnion. Thx Much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is worded a little confusing, but from what I gather you are just looking for an intermediary class to perform the mapping of an input variable to a string. You mention that you don't want there to be hard-coded string literals; The logical remedy here would be to declare a series of constants for them (perhaps at the top of your intermediary mapping class?).

```
public class Common
{
    public const string STARTDATE = "STARTDATE";
    public const string CUSTOMERNAME = "CUSTOMERNAME";

    public static string GetMappedValue(string inputVariable)
    {
        string mappedTo = null;

        switch(inputVariable)
        {
            case "abc":
                mappedTo = SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT_HERE; //map it 
                break;
            case "xyz":
                mappedTo = FOO;
                break;
            //etc etc...
        }

        return mappedTo;
    }
```